# Unreal Engine C1083

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unreal-engine4, unreal-development-kit

I am unable to use an existing unreal engine 4.19 project on Windows 10 - but my peers can. I keep getting the error:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.13.26128\INCLUDE\cstddef(7): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stddef.h': No such file or directory

I have an identical visual studio install to my peers, including full Universal CRT and Windows 8.1/10 SDK. The only difference is that this is a fresh machine install; what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it - Delete the intermediate directory if you've failed the build once. Stores a cache of the VC++ resources in here.